# Filtering eloquent relationship whereHas not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table `cities` and a relationship with `headquarters` table. This is the relatonship in `City.php`.

```php
public function headquarters() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Headquarter'); 
}
```

And in my controller I'm trying to get cities who has headquarters that are physical.

```php
$city_headquarters = City::whereHas('headquarters', function($query) {
   $query->where('headquarter_type', 'physical');         
})->get();
```

I don't get any errors but if there's at least one physical headquarter I get even those whose `headquarter_type` are not physical.

Is it the query right or how can I get only physical headquarters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query is getting all cities having at least one headquarter having `headquarter_type`  set as `physical`

If you want only cities having ONLY physical headquarter then you should use this:

```
$city_headquarters = City::whereDoesntHave('headquarters', function($query){
   $query->where('headquarter_type', '<>', 'physical');  
})->get();
```

If you want to eagerload only Physical headquarters, then:

```
$city_headquarters = City::whereHas('headquarters', function($query) {
   $query->where('headquarter_type','physical');
})->with([
    'headquarters' => function($query) {
          $query->where('headquarter_type', 'physical');
    }
])->get();
```

Then you can do:

```
foreach($city_headquarters as $city) {
   foreach($city->headquarters as $physical_headquarter) {
      $physical_headquarter->[...]
   }
}
```

Comment: Cities may have both physical and virtual headquarters, in this case i'm trying to get only physical one

Comment: I have edited my answer as I think I have understood what you are trying to do :)